# Easy way to convert all int to char?

Tags: java, oop

I was just curious if there was an easy way to convert the int or numbers that are inputted into the program below to letter or characters without making huge changes or rewriting the program. Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SLP4 {

    public int find(final int[] data, final int key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            if (data[i] > key)
                return -1;
            else if (data[i] == key)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int arr[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        SLP4 search = new SLP4();
        System.out.print("Enter the number to find its place: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        int n = search.find(arr, num);
        if ((n >= 0) && (n < arr.length)) {
            System.out.println("Found at element: " + n);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use `toString()` method?

Comment: Which part do you want to change?

Comment: Instead of sorting numbers or integers sort letters. Is this a total program rewrite? I'm learning

Comment: why would you wanna do that? integers are much easier to sort.

Comment: total rewrite, should take 3 minutes

Comment: i meant to say search not sort. My appologies

Comment: @dranrebdino The specifications have changed I guess.  Now the User enters chars not ints

Comment: It's better style instead of `final int arr[] = new int[10];` to write `final int[] arr = new int[10];`. This puts the various pieces of the type part of the declaration together, on the same side of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `find` method to

```
public int find(final char[] data, final char key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        if (data[i] == key)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;

}
```

and the input as

```
    final char arr[] = new char[10];
    System.out.println("Enter 10 chars");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = ((String) input.next()).charAt(0);
        }

    System.out.print("Enter the number to find its place: ");
    char num=((String) input.next()).charAt(0);
    int n = search.find(arr, num);
    if ((n >= 0) && (n < arr.length)) {
        System.out.println("Found at element: " + n);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
```

**edit**

assume input will have `Enter` pressed after each char inputted

Comment: Yes this worked very nicely, rewrote it within 5 minutes or so. Just needed to add the
    SLP4 search = new SLP4();

Comment: Yeah, sorry my class was named differently so I forgot to add

Comment: no problem, this works just fine thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the `int` with an empty `String`:

```
int numberVar = 0; //example value
String convertedInt = "" + numberVar;
```

That will turn the number into a `String`. To reverse, all you need to do is

```
int shortcut = Integer.parseInt(convertedInt, 10); //shortcut == numberVar
```

I have interpreted your question as wanting to turn an `int` into a `String`, though you do use the word characters, so more interpretations are possible.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was downvoted? Or is this just part of the unofficial hazing to keep new users out of the community?

Comment: did you read the question and comments - how does your answer provide a solution?  If you are not sure of the question then seek clarification

Comment: @ScaryWombat Those comments appeared after I submitted my answer. You interpreted the question a bit differently than I did; I don't see how that warrants a downvote.